# How can I turn/tranpose these columns into rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, count, sql-server-2012

This MUST be a simple one, I've very reluctantly asked this question - but I can't work it out. I have a query which (in a roundabout way) returns 2 counts:

```
Col1 | COL2
123    456
```

But I need to return:

```
123 | COL1
456 | COL2
```

**What I've Tried**

I've looked at `UNPIVOT` but since these are simple (independent) rows it seems unnecessary (i.e. I don't need to pivot/unpivot an identifier or anything).

**The Query**

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN [CONDITION] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Col1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [CONDITION] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Col2
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: `UNION ALL` will help I guess..

Answer (score 2):

Use a `UNION`:

```
SELECT COL1 AS VALUE, 'COL1' AS COL
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT COL2 AS VALUE, 'COL2' AS COL
FROM yourTable
```

If you want to select from the entire `UNION` query, you can wrap it and select out:

```
SELECT t.VALUE,
       t.COL
FROM
(
    SELECT COL1 AS VALUE, 'COL1' AS COL
    FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COL2 AS VALUE, 'COL2' AS COL
    FROM yourTable
) t
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Tim! I did originally have a `UNION` in order to get the 2 separate counts (i.e. 2 separate queries) but then promised it away, so I think sub consciously was steering clear of `UNION ALL`

Comment: Will do, have to wait for the time to allow me to first.

Comment: One quick question - you have `FROM` here, how do I 'from' on this one result set? Create a temp table? Seems quite verbose.

Comment: Actually, I think I know the answer, I'll set variables in the first select which does the counting.